# Django inlineformset will not submit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

My application has two models, Recipe and RecipeIngredient, related by foreign key. Each Recipe may have many different RecipeIngredients (and different number of associated ingredients for each recipe). So using a dynamic formset to assign ingredients to a recipe seems to be the best approach.

I have a simple form that has a user enter a quantity and select a unit and ingredient from a dropdown. As a standalone form it works fine.

Unfortunately, I cannot get any formset incorporating it to submit.

I have searched many of the different formset Q&As here on StackOverflow but cannot see where the problem is. When I click 'submit', the form blinks and refreshes in place, with the entered values still in the form. No objects are created. No errors report to the console nor to the browser. The related code:

The models:

```html
class RecipeBase(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=False)
    creation_date = models.DateField("Record creation date",auto_now_add=True)
    creation_user = models.CharField("Record creation user",max_length=150)
    lastupdated_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    lastupdated_user = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(RecipeCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='recipes')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(RecipeSubcategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='recipes')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
        
class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,null=False)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=3,null=False)
    referenced_unit = models.ForeignKey(UnitDetail,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referenced_ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_recipe = models.ForeignKey(RecipeBase,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ingredients')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)[:8]
```

The call to enter ingredients:

```html
<a class='btn btn-success' href="{% url 'recipes:addingredient' pk=recipe_details.pk %}">Add Ingredients</a>
```

Calls the view:

```html
class AddIngredientView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddIngredientForm
    model = RecipeIngredient
    template_name = 'addingredientmultiple2.html'
    success_url = "recipes:listrecipes"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        parent_recipe_id = RecipeBase.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        data = super(AddIngredientView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['ingredients'] = AddIngredientFormset(self.request.POST)
            data['parent_recipe_id'] = parent_recipe_id
        else:
            data['ingredients'] = AddIngredientFormset()
            data['fixture'] = parent_recipe_id
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        fixture = RecipeBase.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = AddIngredientFormset(self.request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            ingredients = formset.save()
            for recipeingredient in ingredients:
                #recipeingredient.creation_user = str(request.user)
                #recipeingredient.lastupdated_user = str(request.user)
                recipeingredient.parent_recipe_id = parent_recipe_id
                #recipeingredient.user = user
                recipeingredient.save()

        return super(AddIngredientView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Using form and formset:

```html
class AddIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    quantity = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'data-placeholder': 0.00,'size': '8','label_tag': ''}))
    referenced_unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UnitDetail.objects.all())
    referenced_ingredient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Ingredient.objects.all())

    class Meta():
        model = RecipeIngredient
        fields = ('quantity','referenced_unit','referenced_ingredient',)

AddIngredientFormset = inlineformset_factory(RecipeBase,RecipeIngredient,form=AddIngredientForm,extra=1,can_delete=True)
```

And template:

```html
{{ ingredients.media.css }}

<div class="container">

<h2>Add ingredients to {{ referring_recipe_name }}</h2>
<h4>{{ referring_recipe_id }}</h4>

</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
    <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">{% csrf_token %}


        <table class="table">
            {{ ingredients.management_form }}

            {% for form in ingredients.forms %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                {% endif %}
                <tr class="formset_row">
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <td>
                            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                    {{ hidden }}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                            {{ field }}
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <input class='btn btn-success' type="submit" value="Save"/> <a href="{% url 'recipes:listrecipes' %}">back to the list</a>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'ADD INGREDIENT',
        deleteText: 'REMOVE',
        prefix: 'ingredients'
    });
</script>

{{ ingredients.media.js }}
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to adapt `CreateView` in this way. It adds a single form `form` to the template context. Since you don't include this in the template, the form will never be valid, so `form_valid` is never going to run.

Comment: @Alasdair Good to know, thanks. I had been trying as a function but getting nowhere, and then I came across [link](https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d) which used CreateView and which worked beautifully. But even if I include {{form.as_p}} to render that form, it still has the same behavior.

Comment: That example is different - it is adding a form and an inline formset in the same view. It doesn't make sense for you to include `{{ form }}` since that form is the same form as in your formset.